# How to solve ${\partial^2y\over \partial x^2}={1\over v^2}{\partial^2y\over \partial t^2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

How to solve this Differential Equation

$${\partial^2y\over \partial x^2}={1\over v^2}{\partial^2y\over \partial t^2}$$

I found this as the partial differential equation of progressive waves.
The equation of a progressive wave is $y=a\sin(\omega t-\phi)$
and $v$ is the velocity of the wave.

Comment: Try a solution in the form $y=Au(x-vt)+Bw(x+vt)$. It is very easy to solve!

Can you see the physical meaning of this? It's two traveling waves in opposite directions.

Answer (score 5):

If $v$ is a constant, you can refer to what's is called [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula):
$$
y(x,t)= \frac{1}{2}\left[g(x-vt) + g(x+vt)\right] + \frac{1}{2v} \int_{x-vt}^{x+vt} h(\xi) \, d\xi,
$$
where the function $g$ is determined by the initial condition $y(x,t)|_{t=0}=g(x)$, and $h$ is determined by the initial condition $\partial y/\partial t|_{t=0} = h(x)$. The physical meaning is that what initially this wave is like will be propagate to left and right in a velocity of $v$.

---

A typical example is the [plane wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave):
$$
y(x,t) = A\sin(kx-\omega t + \phi) + B\sin(kx+\omega t + \psi),
$$
where the wave number $k= \omega/v$, $v$ is the velocity in the equation, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

Comment: I thought the waves in both directions need not be the same function in general. i.e. $g_1(x-vt) + g_2(x+vt)$ should satisfy the pde. Depending on initial conditions, they get fixed.

Comment: @Macavity You are right. Once plugging in $y(x,0) = g(x)$ and $y_t(x,0) = h(x)$, $g_1$ and $g_2$ will be fixed to be this common $g$.